# Where can I download 64 bit geoprocessing for ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, installation, download, 64bit, background-geoprocessing

Where can I download the 64 bit geoprocessing for ArcGIS 10.3?

I know it can be done from the instalation CD, but I don't have access to it at my work.

Do I just have to install [ArcGIS 10.1 Service Pack 1 for (Desktop, Engine, Server)](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1913)
?

Comment: It's been ages since ArcGIS shipped on CD.  Media kits are ***only*** available through the customer portal ([my.esri.com](http://my.esri.com)).  You should certainly apply relevant patches as appropriate, but a 10.1 SP is not applicable to 10.3 media.

Comment: Whoever handles your GIS (usually, either it's own department or merged as part of IT) should have all of your installations and licensing. They would be who to contact to get the 64 bit installation file.

Comment: 64 bit geoprocessing, as @Vince says, is available through Esri's Customer portal [My Esri](my.esri.com) and is called **ArcGIS for Desktop Background Geoprocessing (64 bit)**, and is located in the portal through the ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3 Downloads link